# How to open up NuGet Console

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and 2019.

I want to install a NuGet package through the NuGet Console. I have the commands in my clipboard to do so but i don't know how to open it up or where the NuGet Console is so i can  paste it in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open up NuGet Console Just by following the mentioned Steps:

**Tools [tab] -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Console [Click On It]**

The Console should pop up.

**Note:** Bare in Mind that this may be for **Visual Studio 2015 or Newer** (if i am wrong be sure to Request an edit)